# Problem with php and json

Tags: php, json

Could some one please help me out on this I have the following json string

```
string(1223) "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback({"ResultSet":{"Query":"google","Result":[{"symbol":"GOOG","name": "Google Inc.","exch": "NMS","type": "S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GOOG.MX","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "MEX","type": "S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.F","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "FRA","type": "S","exchDisp":"Frankfurt","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}})"
```

But I cannot seem to get anywhere with it. Basically I want to just loop out the the results which are

```
[{"symbol":"GOOG","name": "Google Inc.","exch": "NMS","type": "S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GOOG.MX","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "MEX","type": "S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.F","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "FRA","type": "S","exchDisp":"Frankfurt","typeDisp":"Equity"}]
```

Sorry my question is how can I loop or even print the first result for example

```
{"symbol":"GOOG","name": "Google Inc.","exch": "NMS","type": "S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"}
```

Comment: Oops I misunderstand question wrong in the beginning also because of your formatting a little bit you need to specify how you query(API) for that data(JSON-P). You should not provide callback to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is not JSON, it is JSON-in-Script. Notice the fragment that says:

`YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(...)`

When a browser receives the above mentioned script (actually a javascript code) it will call the `YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback` function, passing the JSON data as the argument.

You did not mention if you want to access the JASON data on the server side or client? It its server side (PHP) then you can use regular expressions or string replacement functions to extract the portion you like. The you can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to convert the resulting string into an associative array.

Edit ----

A quick and dirty hack for converting JSONP to JSON:

```
<?php
    $text = 'YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback({"ResultSet":{"Query":"google","Result":[{"symbol":"GOOG","name": "Google Inc.","exch": "NMS","type": "S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GOOG.MX","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "MEX","type": "S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.F","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "FRA","type": "S","exchDisp":"Frankfurt","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}})';
    # //CONVERT JSONP to JSON\\
    $text = preg_replace('/.+?({.+}).+/', '$1', $text); 
    # \\CONVERT JSONP to JSON//
    $data = json_decode($text);
    var_dump($data);
    var_dump($data->ResultSet->Result[0]);
    var_dump($data->ResultSet->Result[0]->symbol);
    var_dump($data->ResultSet->Result[0]->name);
    # etc etc
?>
```

Comment: Which would be the best way to do it client or server side ?

Comment: I am not sure where you're grabbing that string from. You mentioned php in the tags and a print_r of the result so I posted a PHP solution. If you're using Yahoo JavaScript libraries, you should be able to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is not just a JSON string, it's a JSON string prepended by a call to a JSON function. This is quite certainly a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) call.
You must write the `YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(data)` javascript function and get the Json there. Check the JSONP query, you should be able to alter the name of this backreference function if you want another name, it's usually on of the parameter in the GET query.

Now you are maybe calling it directly from PHP and you are not in js envirronment. so you must write something in your PHP code to remove the `YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(` part and the `)` at the end **before** parsing it as JSON data..